# How to calculate $y'(0)$ in system of implicit equation

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

How to calculate $y'(0)$ in system of implicit equation?

I'm given a system of implicit equations, namely

\begin{align*}
1. \quad &f_1 =  x\cos z+y\cos x+z\cos y = 0\\
2. \quad &f_2=\sin x + \sin y - \sin z = 0
\end{align*}

I've already proven via the implicit function theorem that these equations can be solved localy at $(0,0,0)$ for $y(x),z(x)$

Now I want to calculate $y'(0)$.

\begin{align*}
1. \quad &\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}=\cos z-xz'\sin z+y'\cos x-y\sin x+z'\cos y-zy'\sin y = 0\\
2. \quad &\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}=\cos x + y'\cos y - z'\cos z = 0
\end{align*}

I suppose I can already plug in $x= 0$. Then...

\begin{align*}
1. \quad &\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(0,y,z)=\cos z+y'+z'\cos y-zy'\sin y = 0 \Rightarrow y'=-\frac{\cos z+z'\cos y}{1-z\sin y}\\
2. \quad &\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(0,y,z)=1 + y'\cos y - z'\cos z = 0 \Rightarrow y'=\frac{z'\cos z-1}{\cos y}
\end{align*}
Is that OK so far? Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: you jow that $y(0)=z(0)=0$, so use it!!!

Comment: @TitoEliatron How do I know that $y(0)=z(0)=0$? I only know that $f_1(0,0,0) = 0$ and $f_2(0,0,0) = 0$, don't I?

Comment: That's why!!! Since the equations holds at $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$. So, when you "solve" for $y$ and $z$, it remains true: that is, $y(x)$ and $z(x)$ pass through this point.

Comment: @TitoEliatron OK I understand. So I have for $f_1$: $y'=-1-z'$ and for $f_2$: $y'=-1+z'$ so $2y'(0) = -2 \Rightarrow y'(0) 
= -1$, correct?